# Disabled state that cannot be changed; Hide or Show?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design

I have a privacy setting during a Creation wizard that contains two options via ratio buttons: Public and Private. By selecting Private, the user can later to change this setting to Public in an Edit dialog. However, if Public is selected and committed, whether during Creating or Editing state, this change cannot be undone. In other words, Public **cannot** be reverted to Private state.

My question is, should I still expose the Privacy settings (two disabled radio buttons with 'Private' selected) to the user even though they cannot make any changes EVER?

My inclination would be to show it so the user is aware of the state but since the setting is not longer editable, it seems a bit useless to show it.

Comment: Make it a non-input field (just a block of text) stating that it's public and why it can't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that I am not getting your requirement right, but are the radio buttons essential? Can you instead provide something like,

[image]

On click of the button, you can provide the confirmation dialog, notifying the user that it is a non reversible action.

Next time when user visits the page, there can be a notification label specifying that the content is public.

*Needless to say, that the color of button should be appropriate to your style, I just cooked up something quickly.*

Comment: Thank you. This could potentially work however I will get into some modal on modal situation since the form wizard is in a modal dialog. But the approach is worth noodling over.